Does fixcmex work with the mlmodern fonts?
There is a problem with the lm fonts.  At some sizes the delimiters and the big operations (summation sign, etc) do not scale with the size of the font.  The package fixcmex corrects this.  (Hopefully the problem will be fixed in the original fonts eventually?).
The mlmodern fonts are a darker version of lm.  See Fatter Computer Modern for a motivation for this darker font.  mlmodern apparently depends directly on lm since it requires that lm be installed in order to work.
Therefore, the question arises: would the fix to lm provided by fixcmex also fix mlmodern?

The problem is not in the fonts as such, just in the legacy-compatibility declaration  of them in the default math setup. It just changes the declarations of cmex and lmex looking at omxmlex.fd it would benefit from the same fix (or better suggest to the mlmodern maintainer to offer that as an option)
Unlike the cm extension font it only appears to be available at one design size so an equivalent declaration would be
\DeclareFontFamily{OMX}{mlmex}{}

\DeclareFontShape{OMX}{mlmex}{m}{n}{%
   <-> mlmex10%
   }{}

Or you could perhaps use the cm font at smaller sizes which would be
\DeclareFontFamily{OMX}{mlmex}{}

\DeclareFontShape{OMX}{mlmex}{m}{n}{%
    <-7.5> cmex7
    <7.5-8.5> cmex8
    <8.5-9.5> cmex9
    <9.5-> mlmex10
  }{}%



original

version 1

version 2

\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{mlmodern}

\makeatletter
\def\fixcmex@fix{%
%\DeclareFontShape{OMX}{mlmex}{m}{n}{%
%   <-> mlmex10%
%}{}
%
\DeclareFontShape{OMX}{mlmex}{m}{n}{%
    <-7.5> cmex7
    <7.5-8.5> cmex8
    <8.5-9.5> cmex9
    <9.5-> mlmex10
  }{}%
%
\SetSymbolFont{largesymbols}{normal}{OMX}{mlmex}{m}{n}%
\SetSymbolFont{largesymbols}{bold}{OMX}{mlmex}{m}{n}%
}

\AtBeginDocument{%
  \begingroup
    \check@mathfonts
    \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter
      \split@name\expandafter\string\the\textfont\thr@@\@nil
      \aftergroup\fixcmex@fix
  \endgroup
}

\makeatother
 
\begin{document}


{\footnotesize $(x) + \left(\frac{a}{b}\right)$}
  }

\bigskip
{\normalsize $(x) + \left(\frac{a}{b}\right)$}

\bigskip
{\LARGE $(x) + \left(\frac{a}{b}\right)$}



\end{document}

